# What kind of Lambda Expression has an input but doesn't use it?

Tags: c#, lambda

At work I came across this line of code:

```
String Key = "ThisKey";
Expression<Func<object, object>> test = t => key.ToString();
```

I understand that 'test' is a variable that holds an expression but what is the point of declaring 't' when it isn't used on the other side of the lambda operator?

Comment: Side note: often unused parameter named `_` like `_ => key.ToString()`. Such constructs frewuently found in event handlers when one does not care about incoming arguments (i.e. button click triggered in very well defined case) but still need to define function: `button.Click += (unused1, unused2)=> DoSomehting(button)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it was defined as `Func<object, object>`; if defined as `Func<obj>`, no params would be required.  The last type is the return type, and every type before that is a parameter type passed in.  Note that when you execute it, it would be done via:

```
test(<paramhere>);
```

or

```
test.invoke(<paramhere>);
```

So even though it's not used in the expression, depending on the actual context the underlying component doesn't know what may be getting passed in.